# Apple Game Center sandbox: players invitations work but NOT auto-match

Tags: sandbox, game-center, multiplayer

I've implemented Multi-player in my IOS game using the standard matchmaking interface screen. Everything works well if I invite another player in the sandbox : the other player receives the push notification, the game is launched etc... and we can enjoy a cool multiplayer session.

The problem is when I try to use auto-match (without inviting a specific friend). I start the game on 2 devices, launch the same standard matchmaking interface screen and click on "play now" on both.
Then I wait for 5 minutes before matchmakerViewController fails with the error:
"The requested operation could not be completed due to an error communicating with the server"

Does it mean auto-match doesn't work in sandbox?

Thank you for your help!

here's my code:

```
- (IBAction) hostMatch:(id)sender
{   
    GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    request.minPlayers = 2;
    request.maxPlayers = 2;

    GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
    mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];        
}
```

Comment: by the way, the [GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] queryActivityWithCompletionHandler returns 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your problem might be without seeing the code, but auto-match definitely works on sandbox. For me the following does the trick:

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[[GKMatchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
request.minPlayers = 2;
request.maxPlayers = 4;
GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request] autorelease];
mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's weird cause It seems I'm using the same code (I updated my post with it)! Do you simply click on "play now" button on the 2 devices?

Comment: yep, I just click on Play Now. It's odd that invitations work fine for you and automatch doesn't, for us it was harder to get the invitations to work and auto match has always worked fine.

Comment: can I ask you a few more questions? what device do you use for tests? which OS version? I use ipad OS4.3.1 and ipod touch OS4.2.1

Comment: Yes no problem. The easiest way to make tests for automatch is to run two simulators (I think you'll need two macs), or one simulator and one device. For invitations, in my experience, they only way to make them work is on devices. I can get automatch to work both with two IPad simulators (4.3), one simulator (4.3) and one IPad (4.3.1), two IPads (both 4.3.1) or one IPad (4.3.1) and one IPhone (4.3). Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi! I just realized that it works with the bundle ID of the free version of my app and not with the bundle ID of the paid one... very strange! I'm asking Apple about that issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have a fix to the game center invite problem . So follow the steps:-
1- check that your push notifications are on in settings and friend invites are on in your game center account setting.
2-now install the latest version of fruit ninja game
3-open game center and sign in, then put it in background
3-open fruit ninja directly goto new game=>multiplayer=>gamecenter
4-now you will see two options ( invite friend & play now at the top right corner)
5-hit the play now button, so the game center will find the uninvited game for you.
6- when the game starts and you are able to see your uninvited friend name at the top right corner. After the game finishes, go directly to game center in the background and in your games section and go into fruit ninja in game list. Here you will see the recently played option. Touch it. Here you will see at the top of the list a player name ( whom you played with ) touch the name and send him friend request immediately.
7-if he accepts request goto friends=>(your recently added friend)=>gameplayed together(frut ninja)=>hit play(at upper right)
8-now the game will open up and u will see the GC page hit the invite button choose the recently added friend, and then send , waiting for him and ready to play.

Now your gc id have verified and you can invite any of your friends and can play any game (which supports invite feature).